Fetching a single file instead of all content
I'm working with Nuxt Content and I'm trying to fetch a specific file from my content directory. Currently, when I make a GET request to http://localhost:3000/api/_content/query/, it returns all files (.md and .json) in JSON format.
How can I modify my request or configuration to retrieve only a single, specific file?
